# How can I set a batch file to find a file and show its emplacement?

Tags: file, batch-file, path

I need this for a basic program. What i can do so far is track if a predefined file exists, but not much more.
I'm trying to do this:

1. Select a file
2. See if it exists
3. Find the path to it
4. save the path under a variable, or something like that
5. Show the path to the user
6. (Execute the file, optional)

Is there a way to do it, and what is the script?
Please tell me if i am not clear.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear is, what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Endoro I don't know any code beyond the beginner-area, haven't tried anything yet, can you tell me how to save a path under a variable or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setLocal
set /p file=choose a file: 
set /p option=do you want to execute the file?[y/n]
if "%option%" equ "y" set /p directory=directory where you want to execute the file:
if "%option%" equ "Y" set /p directory=directory where you want to execute the file:

if not exist "%directory%\" echo directory does not exist %% exit /b 3    


if not exist %file% echo file does not exists && exit /b 1
for %%F in (%file%) do ( 
  set file_atr=%%F
  set full_path=%%~fF
)
if "%file_atr::~0,1%" equ "d"  echo this is a directory && exit /b 2

echo the full path is : %full_path%
if "%option%" equ "y" (
  pushd %directory%
  call  %full_path%
  popd

)
if "%option%" equ "Y" (
  pushd %directory%
  call  %full_path%
  popd

)
endLocal
```

Comment: Кат гледам не си простак! Благодаря!

Comment: Kinda what i wanted, but this only works in the folder where the batch file is, how can i make it work on the entire C: drive?

Comment: You want to execute the file recursively in each directory in C:\ or you want to have an option to choose the directory?If it's the second - I've made some edits in my answer...

Comment: I prefer the 1st one, because whenever i don't find the file, it would just tell me where the file is